# Parse Json data jQuery each

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting json response like this

```
{"item_id":"1","item_title":"Item 1"}{"item_id":"2","item_title":"Item 2"}
```

how would I parse this for each data returned?

Tried

```
$.ajax({
                          url: 'linktojson',
                          type: "post",
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (response) {
                              //console.log('isok');
                              if (response.item_id) {
                                 $('#posts').html(response.item_id);
                              }
                          }
                        });
```

but works only if I have 1  item in the response.

thank you!

Comment: response can't be a series of objects, needs to only one object. Run your response through jsonlint.com to check validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you return valid `JSON` from server then You can traverse the `json` object using `$.each` like

```
success: function (response) {
    $.each(response,function(i,item){
        $('#posts').append(item.item_id+"<br />"); 
    });
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/DxaaV/

Answer (score 1):

That isn't valid JSON, it works with one element only.

Read [JSON](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

OR use **json_encode** on PHP side (assuming you are using PHP)

Comment: it is json_encode but foreach , I see what you are saying. let me try

Comment: if you have many arrays, merge all of them into a single one and then use json_encode

Answer (score 1):

You should get an array of objects like this:

```
var variable = [{"item_id":"1","item_title":"Item 1"}, {"item_id":"2","item_title":"Item 2"}];
```

So modify the response to be like above.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ6Fc/